# Icon Overlay Like SVN

Tags: c++, shell-extensions

I want to make an icon overlay like here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7484/How-to-overlay-an-icon-over-existing-shell-objects

I downloaded this source code and tried to build solution on visual studio 2010 but I get this error:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:/Windows/SysWow64/regsvr32
File: f:/dd/vctools/vc7libs/ship/atlmfc/scr/atl/atls/atlbase.cpp

Expression: 0

For more information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press retry to debug the application)
```

Have anyone made this code work or there is another way to put an icon overlay maybe in java or c# or even on c++?

I want icon overlay like svn add icon overlays.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: We'd be ahead if you clicked Retry so we knew what assertion failed.  The typical problem is UAC, it stops Visual Studio from modifying the registry.  Right-click its shortcut and select "Run as administrator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should build 64-bit shell extensions for a 64-bit system. The path "C:/Windows/SysWow64/regsvr32" indicates that you are registering a 32-bit DLL on a 64-bit system.

Comment: how change the path on visual studio? is this on code because with ctrl+f haven't found this path on solution.

Comment: @user783029: Is regsvr32 run as part of project build? If so, it must be specified in the post-build step. Try creating a new x64 project configuration for the project first of all. Then see what happens. @ HansPassant's note is also valuable: if x64 build still fails, run "Visual Studio x64 Win64 Command Prompt" elevated and type `rergsvr yourdll.DLL` in it. "32" in the name of the utility is confusing -- it is actually a 64 bit app. The 64 bit version is located in C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe, or wherever your system directory is.

Comment: I converted project to 64 bit but get same errors with the difference that now: Program: C:/Windows/System32/regsvr32

Comment: @user783029: Hit Retry and then debug the application. Need to figure out why the assertion is happening during registration.